# Getting wiki page id from the link

Tags: python, wikipedia

I have been using wikipedia library for python.

https://pypi.org/project/wikipedia/

https://wikipedia.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code.html#api

I have a list of wikipidea links (i.e. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swell_(ocean)), and I need to get wikipedia ids to get pages content with:

```
wikipedia.page('id').content
```

Any tips?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to do this:

```
import wikipedia
link = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swell_(ocean)"                                                                                           

title = link.split("/wiki/")                                                                                                                  
page = wikipedia.page(title)                                                                                                                  
page.pageid                                                                                                                                   
'2663672'
```

Comment: Great! A very elegant solution. In the end I did it like this:


`import wikipedia`

`link = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swell_(ocean)"`             
                                                                              
`title = link.split("/wiki/")`             
                                                                                                    
`page = wikipedia.page(title[1])`

`page.content`